# How to scaling the screen size in android(lolliypop)

Tags: android, size, screen, scaling

I want to scale the screen size to 1024x600.

Please let me know how to scale the screen size.

Long time before(ics), i modified the below files.

1.Frameworks/base/services/surfaceflinger/LayerBase.cpp, commitTransaction()
2. frameworks/base/services/input/InputReader.cpp, cookPointerData()

But after jb, i don't know where have to modify.

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: what do you mean scale the screen , explain more please

Comment: I want to use the new lcd display(1024x600).